# snapping code: from separate checks to 1 formula

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm working on a 3D-project with three.js and webGl. I've written a function to check for 2 objects to be near each other and thus "snap" to each other.

The objects don't move on the Y-axis, so I only have to check the 4 sides of each object against the side of all other objects in the scene. At the moment I'm doing that with this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

            var newBox = updateBoundingBox(elements[i]);

            var snapped = null;

            if (newBox.min.x - box.max.x < 5 && newBox.min.x - box.max.x > -box.size().x / 2//5
                && box.max.z > newBox.min.z && box.min.z < newBox.max.z) {

                activeElement.position.x = newBox.min.x - ((box.max.x - box.min.x) / 2) - 0.5;
                box = updateBoundingBox(activeElement);
                snapped = [elements[i], "X"];
            }

            if (newBox.min.z - box.max.z < 5 && newBox.min.z - box.max.z > -box.size().z / 2//5
                && box.max.x > newBox.min.x && box.min.x < newBox.max.x) {

                activeElement.position.z = newBox.min.z - ((box.max.z - box.min.z) / 2) - 0.5;
                box = updateBoundingBox(activeElement);
                snapped = [elements[i], "Z"];

            }

            if (box.min.x - newBox.max.x < 5 && box.min.x - newBox.max.x > -box.size().x / 2
                && box.max.z > newBox.min.z && box.min.z < newBox.max.z) {

                activeElement.position.x = newBox.max.x + ((box.max.x - box.min.x) / 2) + 0.6;
                box = updateBoundingBox(activeElement);
                snapped = [elements[i], "X"];

            }

            if (box.min.z - newBox.max.z < 5 && box.min.z - newBox.max.z > -box.size().z / 2
                && box.max.x > newBox.min.x && box.min.x < newBox.max.x) {

                activeElement.position.z = newBox.max.z + ((box.max.z - box.min.z) / 2) + 0.5;
                box = updateBoundingBox(activeElement);
                snapped = [elements[i], "Z"];

            }

            if (snapped != null) {

                activeElement.snapped.push(snapped);
                debug.snapped = true;
            }


}
```

But, it is very obvious that the 4 `if`-statements are almost identical, so I was wondering if it was possible to write them in a better/shorter way so I can just loop over them?

Answer (score 1):

1) Do not hard-code the distance that will define 'near', but rather make it a variable/parameter.
2) Split the solution : 1) do we 'approximatively' overlap ? and 2) are we on the left or right, and are we up or down ?
3) Use as much 'standard' code as you can : here 'update' will define a BBox based on a list of points, 'expand' and 'overlaps' will do what-you-guess.

```
var nearDistance = 5;
var newBox new BoundingBox();
var boxSize = null;

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var thisElement = elements[i];

            // newBox is now the BBox of thisElement
            newBox.update(thisElement);

            // do we approximatively overlap ?
            newBox.expand(nearDistance);    
            var overlaps = newBox.overlaps(box);    
            if (!overlaps) continue;

            // are we on the left/right, up/down ??

            newBox.expand(-nearDistance);
            boxSize = box.size() ;  

            var newXPosition = -1, newZPosition = -1;

            if ( newBox.min.x - box.max.x > -boxSize.x / 2) {    
                // left
                newXPosition = newBox.min.x - ((box.max.x - box.min.x) / 2) - 0.5;
            } else {
                // right
               newXPosition = newBox.max.x + ((box.max.x - box.min.x) / 2) + 0.6;
            }

            if (newBox.min.z - box.max.z > -boxSize.z / 2 ) {    
                // up
                newZPosition = newBox.min.z - ((box.max.z - box.min.z) / 2) - 0.5;    
            } else {
                // down
                newZPosition= newBox.max.x + ((box.max.x - box.min.x) / 2) + 0.6;
            }                        

            //adjust position
            activeElement.position.x = newXPosition ;
            activeElement.position.z = newZPosition;

            box.update(activeElement);

            activeElement.snapped.push( /* thisElement was snapped */);
            debug.snapped = true;
            }    
}
```